# Print the current window without the menu and footer

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I need to print the current window of a web page with out the menu and footer. I am using `javascript:window.print()`. I have checked a website using same javascript method which excludes the menu and footers but couldn't able to figure how to exclude them as that web site also using just the window.print method.

Answer (score 2):

Add a media query to your CSS to select for print and create a 'noPrint' class like this:

```
@media print
{
 .noPrint  {display:none}
}
```

Then add the class to any item you don't want to appear on a printed output:

```
<div id=header class="noPrint">Some header text</div>
<div id=content>Some content text</div>
<div id=footer class="noPrint">Some footer text</div>
```

The media query will apply `display:none` to anything marked with the `noPrint` class if the output medium is print, but otherwise will leave everything alone.

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)